# Dockerising Elixir/Phoenix app: (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an Elixir/Phoenix application that I have been working on locally, backed by PostgreSQL. Everything works fine when I'm running via the termainal with `mix phx.server`.

I am now trying to dockerise the application so I can deploy to AWS. I'm following the [Deploying with Docker](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/guides/working_with_docker.html) documentation using Distillery.

I've copied all of the settings verbatim from that page so feel free to look through those configs as I'm using the same ones.

When I try to run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
...

db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
web_1  | 12:05:31.631 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1879.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.093 UTC [54] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.093 UTC [54] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
web_1  | 12:05:32.094 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1877.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.295 UTC [55] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.295 UTC [55] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
web_1  | 12:05:32.296 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1870.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.640 UTC [56] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:32.640 UTC [56] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
web_1  | 12:05:32.641 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1880.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:33.150 UTC [57] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-04-14 12:05:33.150 UTC [57] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
web_1  | 12:05:33.151 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.1875.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
...
```

It's probably a fairly straightforward issue to solve but I haven't done much database admin. My guess is I need to change something in the `config/docker.env` file (from the link above).

If I'm not mistaken the default password for the `postgres` user is blank. But I'm not sure how to set a blank password using that `docker.env` file. Ideally, I'd like to set the username and password myself somewhere during docker's build so I know what user has been created etc (assuming that's a wise thing to do).

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIR, the default password for `postgres` use is `postgres`. Just set it in your `prod.exs` config or where do you load it from.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted uses the standard [Postgres Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

You can extend/configure this image by setting [Environment Variables](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#environment-variables).

Most prominently:

- POSTGRES_PASSWORD
- POSTGRES_USER
- POSTGRES_DB

The `config/docker.env`  you posted also uses environment variables - but only to configure the application - and not the Postgres image. This setup silently assumes the default values from `postgres:10-alpine`.

You can add the env vars the Postgres Image understands and use the existing application configuration.

In order to just make it work with a self picked user name and password. This should suffice:

`config/docker.env`

```
# ...
DATABASE_USER=dbsuperuser
DATABASE_PASS=dbsuperuserpassword
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbsuperuserpassword
POSTGRES_USER=dbsuperuser
# ...
```

**Warning**: The user and password configured with environment variables is a **Superuser**. This should not be the user the appplication connects to the database - event though this tutorial promotes this.